# Rails CORS - simple request: allowed methods option is ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors

I build API based on Rails 5. I use 'rack-cors' gem to control CORS. Below code snipped I wonder about:

```
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: %i()
      end
    end
```

I removed all HTTP methods from allowed methods array however still I can call GET, POST successfully (DELETE is forbidden and I get it). As I can see OPTIONS, GET, POST are ignored because even it's empty I can call server with these methods. Is it normal? If it is so how to forbid e.g. POST using CORS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `methods` value only controls what method names the server sends back in the value of the [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) header in response to a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) — that is, only for non-“simple” requests.

So if your request has characteristics that trigger a preflight, only then will browsers check the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header to see if the request method is allowed, and so only then will the `methods` value you’ve configured have any effect.

Otherwise, your browser will allow any cross-origin `GET` and `POST` that doesn’t trigger a preflight — any “simple” request — without regard to whatever `methods` value you’ve configured.

> how to forbid e.g. POST using CORS?

You can’t forbid “simple” `POST` requests using CORS. You can only forbid non-simple `POST` requests — those that have for whatever reason triggered a preflight.

Or, by using the `headers` option, you can set the [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) header value — which will cause the browser to disallow any non-simple preflighted requests that have request headers with names other than the header names you’ve specified with that `headers` option.

Comment: so [:get, :head, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options] gets the same effect as [:put, :patch, :delete] ?

Comment: @mike927 for simple requests, yeah, those have the same effect ー which is to say, they both have no effect at all. But for preflighted requests, they instead have different effects ー which is to say, exactly the effects you would expect them to have. Specifically, a preflighted POST request will disallowed by browsers if that method value doesn't have :post

Comment: hey, finally I got it! I felt confused how it is possible to perform preflight request along with GET. I forgot about other restrictions than HTTP method, like custom header though. Definitely best answer !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow only specific methods, say GET and OPTIONS, try this:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :options]
  end
end
```

More info [here](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).

Comment: no it is not my question. I would like to know why I can use GET, POST even if there are excluded.

Comment: I see your point, may I ask, how do you make your calls to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Rack-cors gem set default value of methods and headers to :get

So if you pass empty string or empty array or nil, it would take it as :any so it is allowing get, post etc requests.

Comment: Check code at line # 348 https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/master/lib/rack/cors.rb

Comment: I don't see `opts[:methods]` being set to `:any` anywhere in that code for blank array. If `opts[:methods]` is not passed, it is picking up `[:get]`

Comment: Check line # 351 

ensure_enum(opts[:methods]) || [:get]

Comment: Precisely, check the implementation of [`enure_enum`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/master/lib/rack/cors.rb#L425). It will return nil if opts[:methods] is nil (which isn't the case), else it will send the flatten array of http verbs passed in `opts[:methods]` (which is empty).